# How to combine files

Tags: awk

I have two files.

first file:

```
45  76
77  23
12  93
77  10
82  92
```

second file:

```
89
37
84
10
93
```

I want to combines them in one file
like this

```
89  45  76
37  77  23
84  12  93
10  77  10
93  82  92
```

Answer (score 3):

With `paste`:

```
$ paste file2 file1
89  45  76
37  77  23
84  12  93
10  77  10
93  82  92
```

With `pr`:

```
$ pr -mts'  ' file2 file1
89  45  76
37  77  23
84  12  93
10  77  10
93  82  92
```

With `awk`:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next}{print a[FNR],$0}' OFS='  ' file2 file1
89  45  76
37  77  23
84  12  93
10  77  10
93  82  92
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
$ join file1.txt file2.txt
```

If the files are not sorted try like this:

```
$ paste file2.txt file1.txt
```

Comment: Join requires file to be sorted.

Comment: @sudo_O:- Yes I got  your point. Then probably paste is a good option :)

Comment: @sudo_O:- Yes I agree that join works for sorted files but now I have improved my answer!!! Thanks to you too:)

Answer (score 0):

`paste` is the canonical tool to solve this. Here is a pure bash alternative

```
while IFS= read -r -u 3 line1 && IFS= read -r -u 4 line2;
do
  printf "%s %s\n" "$line2" "$line1";
done 3<first 4<second
```